# Compare two strings without considering spaces or characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

I have a questions regarding this, I have seen some answers using pregmatch and regex to convert into alphanumeric characters only, ie, removing the characters and spaces from the string and match them.

The question is, is this the best way to do this? And the time complexity can be larger if I add this?
Or else is there a method that simply does the job that doesn't take much time? I have to compare the string with the rows in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$no_spaces = preg_replace('/ /', '', $with_spaces)'
```

Then test $no_spaces.

Don't worry about performance unless you will be doing a billion tests.